# Why does multiple modal using twitter bootstrap got error too much recursion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I try to have a modal inside another modal. However, I got an error like `too much recursion` in firefox.

I used the latest jQuery and Twitter bootstrap but still have this problem.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aC74s8) that shows the error

You can find errors in console `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` or `too much recursion`

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ok, it seems like an issue that has been discovered.

(apparently I should use key word "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" instead of "too much recursion" :( )

Here are the solutions.

**1. modify the modal.js**

in this post, https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/5022

@onassar bring up a solution

> Follow up: for anyone working with bootstrap-modal v2.2.0, in the
>   enforceFocus method, commenting out that.$element.focus() seems to fix
>   the issue.
>
> The result of this is the modal's don't get focused upon (pfft, I can
>   do that myself :P), and thus, the multiple modals don't challenge
>   one-another for focus (which resulted in an infinite loop, and a
>   rangerror/recursive loop).
>
> Hope that helps :)

I tried and it works. ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DFLSei))

**2. Use [another plugin](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal) to address this** [Demo](http://jschr.github.com/bootstrap-modal/)

It seems like it works pretty well.

**3. Wait for official solution.**

In their [roadmap](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/wiki/Roadmap), they do want to rewrite this modal plugin at some point.

Answer (score 110):

You can apply the first solution of maxisam answer, without modifying bootstrap files (if you can not, or don't want to).

Just write this line somewhere after bootstrap files have been included.

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {};
```

**Note:** This has been tested with Bootstrap 2 only, not with Bootstrap 3.

Comment: I tried using Bootstrap Modal which has a ModalManager (https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal) for stacking modals. Turns out you need to create and call a modal from within a modal for it to work. This did the trick!

Comment: Thanks, this is way easier than editing the source and I can use it only on pages where it's required.

Comment: @Davo "Make everything as simple as possible, but not simpler." - Albert Einstein; see my answer for a more robust way of doing this that should preserve enforceFocus functionality for other modals

Comment: This is great answer. Saved my lot of time. Do you know why this issue occurs?

Comment: This worked great, but are there any side effects to doing this?

Comment: The fix worked for me too.  I wanted to add that launching 2 modals is not really a valid thing to do.  Launching 2 dialogs is OK, but modals no.  The idea of a modal is that you only get that modal, and cannot click on anything else.  In the case of a dialog you should be able click other things behind the dialog when it's active.  jQuery-ui has the same problem with modals, basically, the multiple modals fight each other for focus.

Answer (score 31):

SmartLove's answer unfortunately falls short; if you're going to no-op `$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus`, you should reset it when your modal closes; the following is directly from our code, about which I have *no qualms* putting into production:

```
// Since confModal is essentially a nested modal it's enforceFocus method
// must be no-op'd or the following error results 
// "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
// But then when the nested modal is hidden we reset modal.enforceFocus
var enforceModalFocusFn = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus;

$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};

$confModal.on('hidden', function() {
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = enforceModalFocusFn;
});

$confModal.modal({ backdrop : false });
```

Comment: I don't know the framework well enough to know precisely what enforceFocus does.  However, it simply *must* be best to set it back to it's original function/value when you are done over-riding it, and this is a best practice across all Javascript frameworks -- for instance it's the kind of thing I learned to do during my 4.5 years using ExtJS.

Comment: what if `ReferenceError: $confModal is not defined` error occurs?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear that `$confModal` is a reference to a modal in my code that has already been instantiated -- just substitute this with a reference to your own instantiated modal

Comment: You could change $confModal with $('modal') for example. It should work using bootstrap.

$('modal').on('hidden', function() {
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = enforceModalFocusFn;
});

Answer (score 7):

**4. Or you could do the following when showing a new modal:**

1. Hide any modal that is currently active
2. Show the new modal
3. When you close the new modal, show previously hidden modal(s)

   ```
   var showModal = function ($dialog) {
       var $currentModals = $('.modal.in');
       if ($currentModals.length > 0) { // if we have active modals
           $currentModals.one('hidden', function () { 
               // when they've finished hiding
               $dialog.modal('show');
               $dialog.one('hidden', function () {
                   // when we close the dialog
                   $currentModals.modal('show');

               });
           }).modal('hide');
       } else { // otherwise just simply show the modal
           $dialog.modal('show');
       }
   };
   ```

Note: I use `$.one` to only have the listener applied once and not to care about `bind`/`unbind` (`on`/`off`)

Comment: it is a good idea, however, if the 2nd modal is a loading popup modal, usually you would like to keep the previous one on the screen as well.

Comment: loading is something very general and crosscutting the whole project. maybe you could put together a custom component for that, so it wouldn't interfere with bootstrap. (at least that's what I've done in my project)

Answer (score 3):

For Bootstrap 4, replace :
`$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.**enforceFocus**`
By 
`$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.**_enforceFocus**`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following css. It worked for me.

```
span.select2-container {
    z-index:10050;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 5 version of @Dexygen answer:

```
const enforceModalFocusFn = bootstrap.Modal.prototype._enforceFocus ;    
const onMyModalHidden = function(){
   bootstrap.Modal.prototype._enforceFocus = enforceModalFocusFn;
}

//let modalElem = ...;
modalElem.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', onMyModalHidden);
bootstrap.Modal.prototype._enforceFocus = function () {};
```

Important note: You have to override the function before the modal is shown. That means i.e. on 'show.bs.modal'. If you initialize override later, i.e. on 'shown.bs.modal' it wont work, because the original function was allready passed.

The same works for offcanvas (that was what I needed), just change .Modal to .Offcanvas and _enforceFocus to _enforceFocusOnElement

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using a stack.

```
var openmodals = [];
$(function(){
  var ts = new Date().getTime();
  $("div.modal").each(function( d ) {
    ts++;
    $( this ).data( "uid", ts );
  });

  // after closing > 1 level modals we want to reopen the previous level modal
  $('div.modal').on('show', function ( d ) {
    openmodals.push({ 'id' : $( this ).data( "uid" ), 'el' : this });
    if( openmodals.length > 1 ){
        $( openmodals[ openmodals.length - 2 ].el ).modal('hide');
    }
  });
  $('div.modal').on('hide', function ( d ) {
    if( openmodals.length > 1 ){
        if( openmodals[ openmodals.length - 1 ].id == $( this ).data( "uid" ) ){
            openmodals.pop(); // pop current modal 
            $( openmodals.pop().el ).modal('show'); // pop previous modal and show, will be pushed on show 
        }
    } else if( openmodals.length > 0 ){
        openmodals.pop(); // last modal closing, empty the stack
    } 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can omit: `tabindex="-1"`, at the top of modal, you can open the modal in the way: `$('#modal').show();` and close: `$('#modal').hide();`

Note: [JQuery](https://code.jquery.com/) is required for this to work.