# Error: "Too much recursion"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Firebug shows me the following error: `too much recursion` , I tried a lot to determine what causes me this error, but in vain

This is my JavaScript code:

```
$(".scan").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var docName = $("#nomPJ").val();
    $(this).attr("nomDoc",docName);
});
```

Another on a separated js file:

```
$(".scan").live("click",function(event){
    alert("frame");
    var e = event.target;
    nomDoc = $(e).attr("nomDoc");
    idDoc = $(e).attr("idDoc");
    alert("id"+idDoc);
    $("#title").text(nomDoc);
    $("#modal-body").empty().append('<iframe frameBorder="0"  height="90%" width="98%" style="margin-left: 5px"  src="/GRH/Scan.jsp?nomDoc=' + nomDoc + '&idDoc='+idDoc+'"></iframe>');
    $("#myModal").modal({ dynamic: true });
});
```

The html element:

```
<a href="" class="scan" idDoc="1" nomDoc="" target="_blanck">numériser</a>
```

I removed to first code, but the problem still remains.

Comment: Add what line are you getting the error?

Comment: the error in firebug indicates a line in jquery

Comment: i don't know exactly which line causes this , a part from the line of jquery indicated by firebug

Comment: Your code seems fine? May be issue is in some other js code.

Comment: @fatiDev: Then __what__ line is indicated by Firebug? The code as it is right now doesn't have any recursion in it, the problem is probably in some other code.

Comment: open the stack of the exception and look for the first file:line that is at your code (and not jquery code)

Comment: i tried to eliminate line by line in my code , this line is responsible of the error : $("#myModal").modal({ dynamic: true });

Comment: I think the error might be in `alert("frame");` statement. The alert would have to fire up everytime while the page is in memory.

Comment: i removed this alert , the problem is with $("#myModal").modal({ dynamic: true });

Comment: this line is for the customized modal scroll , i removed the js and css file related, and then used just $("#myModal").modal(); the problem is gone

Comment: question: Are you using bootstrap? 
advice: `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers

Comment: yes i'm using bootstrap , i changed to on , thanks

Comment: google chrome , show another error , not the too much recursion error

Comment: which error you got in chrome?

Comment: it shows Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: it's the same error, different message ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23212/discussion-between-fatidev-and-tom-sarduy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, sound like a bug, but I have readed [the docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) and there is not dynamic option, anyway, is well know that the modal bootstrap plugin has some other bugs like the [multiple modal bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649459/twitter-bootstrap-multiple-modal-error).

#### Posible solutions:

1. Modify the modal.js which is not recommended
2. Use another [modal plugin](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal). It seems like it works pretty well.
3. Merge the two click events into one
4. Delete the `dynamic: true` option on `modal()` function, set a fixed width to `#myModal` and `overflow:scroll` using css.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you trying to actually troubleshoot this in some other application, firebug/fox is pretty rough; chrome will help you out a lot more.

If you're feeling your oats, or can't use chrome, [this post](http://danielmontague.com/2015/06/05/too-much-recursion/) saved me from a ton of hassle!

long story short, it goes through logging each function automatically, so

```
function apples () {
  bananas()
}
function bananas () {
  apples()
}
```

becomes

```
function apples () {
  console.log('apples');
  bananas()
}
function bananas () {
  console.log('bananas');
  apples()
}
```

so that you can see *exactly* which functions are wrapped up in the all-to-vague "too much recursion"

happy troubleshooting!