# Maximum call stack size exceeded in Sinatra/twitter bootstrap project

Tags: javascript, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sinatra

I'm using twitter bootstrap in my Sinatra project. So far everything has been ok, but now all of the sudden the error appeared:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
m.matchesSelector
f.extend.filter
f.fn.extend.is
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
e.extend.each
e.fn.e.each
f.fn.extend.trigger
f.fn.(anonymous function)
```

I have no idea what could cause it. **It's caused only** when I click on an input box or submit button and it makes the browser's tab crash. I can't show you the code because it's too complicated. I only need the clue of what I should do first.

Your ideas?

**UPDATE**: It's caused only for `input text` on onblur(?) event: when I go to another tab and press alt+tab or when I click on this `input text`. There are no custom event handlers though.

Comment: Look at the call stack, it's easy to see what pattern it's following. At what point does your code end and the framework code start? What is triggering it to keep re-entering?

Comment: I have no idea where my code starts. how do I know this?

Comment: So did you bother to actually look through what's in the call stack? Surely something in your code is calling something in the framework. Find it.

Comment: if was able to find it, I would create that thread.

Comment: You will have to show us some code...

Comment: i also got the same error here. it's a pain to debug. i'm going through each commit to see when the problem was introduced.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Is there any way to catch the error in debugger? I already did "Enable 'Break on exceptions' in the Chrome Developer Toolbar" but it didn't help at all.

Comment: I suppose there are two js events that invoke each other causing an infinite loop. Look what you have on that field and form.

Comment: This normally occurs when using two modals. Give a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649459/twitter-bootstrap-multiple-modal-error