# Bootstrap Modal blocks select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When the Modal appears there is a select list that is anchored to the top left of the page. Eventually that list will be used to provide navigation options; however I am unable to select an option in the list.  I have tried to set the z-index higher than the modal but nothing seems to work.  Hope someone can shed some light on a solution? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Tool</title>
<!-- Bootstrap v2.3.2 -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="onl btn btn-success btn_online">Submit</button>

<!-- popup message -->
<div id="popup_message" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 class="_c1g">Description</h3>
</div>

<div class="well msg" id="msg" style="max-height:400px;overflow:auto;"></div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn _c1e" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
</div>
```

```
<script src="script/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<!--Bootstrap v3.0.0-->
<script src="script/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('click', '.btn_online', function (e) {
            $('#popup_message').modal('show');
            $("body").append("<select id='my_redirect' style='top:20px;left:20px;z-index:1051;position:absolute;'><option value='' >Select...</option><option value='Page1' >Page1</option><option value='Page2' >Page2</option></select>")

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/cErF4/2/

Comment: @Sinetheta In your fiddle there is no dialog showing. I am using http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css (not 3.0) and then try it.  The options are not selectable.

Comment: Sure, it still works in 2.3.2 though http://jsfiddle.net/cErF4/6/ what browser are you using? And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: FireFox 24, IE10, doesn't matter, I am unable select an option.  I have clients with a script hosted on my site.  The select list is a dashboard that runs on their sites.  If they load a Bootstrap modal I need to still give the user access to the dashboard. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry man, I've been digging for an hour and can't figure out why those browsers suck. I can confirm that the `<select>` won't operate in FF although it will register click events. Very lame.

Comment: It's like the modal is interfering with the <select> but I can't see how if its z-index is lower.  I even tried a top zindex script to push the select higher but it has no affect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39375/discussion-between-sinetheta-and-rob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twitter bootstrap multiple modal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649459/twitter-bootstrap-multiple-modal-error/19190216#19190216)

My assumptions were correct.  The modal enforces focus on itself. The above has the solution created by @SmartLove.  Basically place the following after the bootstrap scripts..

$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {};

Now the select element works as expected! Woo Hoo!

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the issue of a modal blocking all elements beneath it when closed you can also add the following block:

```
<style>
  /*Modal blocking caused issues with selecting objects*/
  .modal { display:none; }
</style>
```