# RequireJS - Manually bundling some libs together

Tags: requirejs

I'm trying to migrate a site to use RequireJS to manage it's JS dependencies. Also I want to bundle some libs together.

Currently we are building a `base.min.js` that comprises underscore, jquery, bootstrap and backbone. They are used all over our site and thus it makes sense to serve them together.

Nevertheless, I think we should have logically the three libs separate by name, thus I have written the following require.config:

```
  require.config({
     baseUrl: '/s/js/libs',
     paths: {
       app: '../app', shims: '../shims'
     },
     map: {
       '*' : {
       // underscore, backbone, jquery and bootstrap are bundled
       'underscore': '../base',
       'backbone': '../base',
       'jquery': '../base',
       'bootstrap': '../base'
        }
     },
     shim:{
        'bootstrap': {
           deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'backbone': {
           deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
           exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'jquery': {exports: '$'}
      }
  });
```

I'm not using the `data-main`; but instead I'm requiring several things:

```
  require(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone", "bootstrap", "../baseapp"],
     function($){
       // Next line fixes the bootstrap issue with double modals taken from:
       // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649459/twitter-bootstrap-multiple-modal-error
       $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {};
       $('.modal').on('shown', function () {
         $('input:text:visible:first, textarea:visible:first', this).focus();
       });
       $('#search').on('shown', function () {
         $('#id_asf-text').focus();
       })

       require(['micro', 'csrf_xhr', 'locale']);
       require(['app/routers']);

     });
```

This however causes the error that `$` is undefined.

The global `window.$` is defined, but it seems that requirejs is not properly detecting it with the `exports` of my shims. Even if I do `exports: 'window.jQuery'` it does not work.

Is this a bug in RequireJS or there a bug in my code? Does `map` and `shim` play well together? Does RequireJS support my use case?

#### Update 2013-11-05

After a long debugging session, I have found that shims are recorded per "real" Module inside RequireJS; so if I just change my shim to be:

```
 shim : {
    '../base': {init: function() {return [$, _, Backbone]}}
 }
```

I do get this array as the first argument to my callback. However I would like them to be exploded, i.e; have each of the returned values as arguments...

I thought that an internal map + paths would work. Like this:

```
  var require = {
     baseUrl: '/s/js/libs/',
     paths: {
       app: '../app',
       shims: '../shims',

       'base-underscore': '../base',
       'base-backbone': '../base',
   'base-jquery': '../base',
   'base-bootstrap': '../base'
     },
     map: {
       '*' : {
       // underscore, backbone, jquery and bootstrap are bundled
       'underscore': 'base-underscore',
       'backbone': 'base-backbone',
       'jquery': 'base-jquery',
       'bootstrap': 'base-bootstrap',
        }
     },
     shim:{
        'base-bootstrap': {
           deps: ['base-jquery'],
           init: function() {return null}
        },
        'base-backbone': {
           deps: ['base-underscore', 'base-jquery'],
           init: function() {return window.Backbone;}
        },
        'base-underscore': {
           init: function() {return window.Underscore;}
        },
        'base-jquery': {
          init: function() {return $}
        }
     }  // shims
  };
```

Unfortunally, it does not. Now the error is: `Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: base-underscore,base-backbone,base-bootstrap,../base`... Notice base-jquery is not listed!

Comment: silly questions 1) you mention `base.min` but your config uses just `base`? 2) if you're not using data-main where is the require.config invoked from?

Comment: @explunit -- A type I changed from base.min.js to base.js be sure my bundle is Ok. I found a workaround I will share in a few minutes.

Comment: @explunit -- Ah! I forgot to answer your sencond question. The call to `require(['jquery', ...` is hard coded in the HTML. This is so, cause I'm progressively translating a Django app that has several base plugins. So, for each page, it may be the case that several JS are needed and no single `data-main` could be easily extracted right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround, but involves a plugin. This is my current solution. On my HTML I have the following `config` (I changed to `require = {...}` idiom so that debugging would be easier):

```js
  var STATIC_URL = "/s/js/libs/";
  var require = {
     baseUrl: STATIC_URL,
     paths: {
       app: '../app',
       shims: '../shims',
     },
     map: {
       '*': {
            'jquery': 'bundler!jQuery',
            'bootstrap': 'bundler!',
            'underscore': 'bundler!_',
            'backbone': 'bundler!Backbone'
        }
     },
     bundler: {url: '../base'}
  };
```

The `bundler.js` plugin lies in my `js/libs`. This is the original CoffeeScript:

```coffeescript
global = @

each = (ary, func) ->
    if (ary)
        i = 0
        while i < ary.length and (what = ary[i]) and func(what, i, ary)
            i += 1

getGlobal = (value) ->
    if not value
        value
    g = global;
    each value.split('.'), (part) ->
        g = g[part]
    g

define
    load: (name, require, onload, config) ->
        base = config.bundler?.url ? '../base'
        require [base], () ->
            if name? and name
                value = getGlobal(name)
                onload(value)
            else
                onload()

    normalize: (name, norm) -> name
```

Probably there should be a way to do this without a `bundler`... I'll keep the question open for while, so that better answers might be provided.

Comment: I'm closing this question as answered. More details at: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/941