# Implementing jQuery DatePicker in Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-datepicker

Created jsfiddle for my issue http://jsfiddle.net/sudiptabanerjee/93eTU/

In modal window issue is on Change Month and Change Year combos.

a) IE 11: everything is working as expected
b) Chrome Version 31, On month combo select, bootstrap modal hides.
c) Firefox v26, Month and Year dropdown is not functional.

Please help.

HTML

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="idTourDateDetails">Tour Start Date:</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="idTourDateDetails" id="idTourDateDetails" readonly="readonly" class="form-control clsDatePicker"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i id="calIconTourDateDetails" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>

                        </div>
                    </div>Alt Field:
                    <input type="text" name="idTourDateDetailsHidden" id="idTourDateDetailsHidden">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

CSS

```
.clsDatePicker {
z-index: 100000;
}
```

JS

```
 $('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
 minDate: '+5d',
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 altField: "#idTourDateDetailsHidden",
 altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is because the modal enforces focus on itself. Here is a solution for this as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649459/twitter-bootstrap-multiple-modal-error/19190216#19190216) . Add the below script to your js file. That's it.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/93eTU/16/)**

**jQuery**

```
// Since confModal is essentially a nested modal it's enforceFocus method
// must be no-op'd or the following error results 
// "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
// But then when the nested modal is hidden we reset modal.enforceFocus
var enforceModalFocusFn = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus;

$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};

$confModal.on('hidden', function() {
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = enforceModalFocusFn;
});

$confModal.modal({ backdrop : false });
```

**For Bootstrap 4:**

```
replace : $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus
By: $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus
```

Comment: Added this only $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {}; Its working fine Thanks http://jsfiddle.net/sudiptabanerjee/93eTU/22/.  But can you give more details on other code and why it is necessary.

Comment: @SudiptaBanerjee See **[this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649459/twitter-bootstrap-multiple-modal-error/19190216#19190216)**

Comment: I get in the browser (confModal is not defined)

Comment: Only adding this: $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {}; should work. Rest is not required :)

Comment: Confirmed that it works with ajax loaded modal as well. The code must be inserted in the file that has the button and not in the ajax loaded file. Working with Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 4):

`jQuery` version of @crftr answer

```
var enforceModalFocusFn = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus;
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
try{
    $confModal.on('hidden', function() {
        $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = enforceModalFocusFn;
    });
    $confModal.modal({ backdrop : false });
}
catch (error) {
    if(error.name != 'ReferenceError')
        throw error;
}
```

Comment: You made my day.
It's also working with dynamically generated modals which get their markup via ajax. I've put it in the document.ready function in which I have a handler for clicking on a modal link and it works out of the box. 

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

MORE EASY... just need to comment this line into your boostrap.js that.enforceFocus().

Comment: Doing changes in a library could looks easier to you, but it could become a nightmare if you want to keep your library up to date afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Surjith's answer, I added a try/catch block to resolve a ReferenceError exception for `confModal` being undefined.

Coffeescript:

```
enforceModalFocusFn = $.fn.modal.Constructor::enforceFocus

$.fn.modal.Constructor::enforceFocus = ->

try
  $confModal.on "hidden", ->
    $.fn.modal.Constructor::enforceFocus = enforceModalFocusFn
    return
  $confModal.modal backdrop: false
catch error
  if error.name != 'ReferenceError'
    throw error
```

Answer (score 0):

add z-index to your datepicker class

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier way to fix this datepicker issue. Make sure the JS is below jquery, jqueryUI  lib calls.

```
$("body").delegate("#date1", "focusin", function () {
      $(this).datepicker(
        {
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true
        }
      );
});


$( "#date1" ).datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround for this issue is removing tabindex="-1" attribute on your div.modal element.Tested on bootstrap 4.