# JQuery datePicker changeYear inside Modal

Tags: jquery, datepicker, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use `DatePicker` inside a bootstrap modal:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it']);

$("#datepicker").datepicker( {showOn:"button",dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', 
     changeYear: true,
     yearRange:'1920:+0',
     buttonImageOnly: true, 
     buttonImage: '/icon-datepicker.png' 

}).on('change',function(){
     $(this).blur()
});
```

But when I select a year from the combobox, the modal disappears. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059598/implementing-jquery-datepicker-in-bootstrap-modal?rq=1). I repost the code:

```
// Since confModal is essentially a nested modal it's enforceFocus method
// must be no-op'd or the following error results 
// "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
// But then when the nested modal is hidden we reset modal.enforceFocus
var enforceModalFocusFn = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus;

 $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};

    $confModal.on('hidden', function() {

  $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = enforceModalFocusFn;
});

$confModal.modal({ backdrop : false });
```