# Month select in datepicker inside a bootstrap-modal won't work in Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-modal

The month select in the datepicker doesn't work in FireFox if it is within a bootstrap-modal.

```
<button class="btn" id="btn">Click Me</button>

<div class="modal hide" id="modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" />        
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({"changeMonth": true});

$('#btn').click(function() {
    $("#modal").modal('show');
});
```

Here is a minified example: http://jsfiddle.net/nKXF2/

I found a simmilar twitter-bootstrap github issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5979

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found two fixes for this bug:

**Fix 1:** If you remove the tabindex attr in div.modal, the month select works just fine. 
*The only issue I had with this solution is that, on IE (any version) you still need to double-click the month dropwdown for it to open up.*

**Fix2:** The second solution you can find at: http://jsfiddle.net/nKXF2/1/ By overriding the enforceFocus function which was proposed in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059598/implementing-jquery-datepicker-in-bootstrap-modal) also, you get the month dropdown to work again.

```
$('#modal').on('show', function () {
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () { };
});
```

I think this second one is the best.

Comment: Second fix did it for me. The event might've changed in more recent Bootstrap version, because I had to use this: `$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal' ...`

Comment: You rock man. The second fix did for me. I was searching for a long time. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Since, Bootstrap 3 we will need to use `$('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {})` instead of `$('#modal').on('show', function () {});`

Comment: In my case this modal function was called `_enforceFocus`, so replacing `$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus` was fixing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First Try to detect only firefox browser

```html
 if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') !== -1) {
  $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function (){};
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but it was because I had padding on the input boxes. Once removed it fixed everything. Which makes me think I hate Firefox even though this was my fault. :P

Comment: Firefox tends to follow the standards just a little closer than the other browsers ... I've noticed that trend for years now.  It doesn't mean that it is worse, just that it leads developers to write better "more standard" code.

But really, this is the sort of thing that should be handled correctly by bootstrap internally.

Answer (score 0):

Having run into this problem, not only did I need to find a solution, but also figure out why it's happening. Turns out that proposed solutions can break some things (and navigating using TAB was important in the project I was fixing).

This [bootstrap issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19971) proved to be very helpful.

Basically modal tries to hoard focus (that's what `enforceFocus` function is for). This is done to prevent navigating outside of the modal while it's open (like when using screen readers or navigating using TAB on keyboard). `datepicker` has it's own popup which is placed outside of the modal. For this reason the month dropdown can't keep focus and instantly closes. This isn't an issue for selecting date on the calendar, because clicking doesn't require focus.

Replacing `enforceFocus` with an empty function does help with the month dropdown, but might allow navigation outside the model even when it's open.

On the other hand `tabindex="-1"` suggest that the element cannot be navigated to, so you can't move focus to a hidden modal using normal means (again using TAB or through some accessibility feature). Possibly, if you remove `tabindex` from the modal it's `enforceFocus` will not be run. The downside would again be, allowing modal to be navigated out of while it's open, but also navigating into it when it's hidden.

From Bootstrap 4 onwards there is also a `focus` option that when set to `false`, will not make the modal hoarding focus (it probably just skips running `enforceFocus`).

```
$("#MyModal").modal({ show: true, focus: false });
```

Needless to say, while more convenient, it has the same problems as replacing `enforceFocus`.

Other options include:

- Using a different datepicker that keeps all it's elements inside the modal
- Using native html datepicker
- Replacing selects inside the datepicker with elements that look the part, but don't require focus to operate

I have no idea why this is an issue in FireFox, but not in other browsers.