# Jquery datepicker & Bootstrap modal Error in (Firefox)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

the month and year dropdowns ("select boxes") are not being opened.

This issue is only on Firefox browser.

Here in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/morrisonrox/ye25dnub/) you can see

**JS**:

```
$('#fecha_registro,#oi_ingreso_date,#oi_int_date,#fecha_nacimiento_add_pac,#r1_fecha_nacimiento_add_pac,#r2_fecha_nacimiento_add_pac').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
    prevText: 'Ant',
    nextText: 'Sig',
    currentText: 'Hoy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '1900:2100'   
});
```

Comment: You can try this one also - [Month and year won't work in firefox in modal][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050641/month-select-in-datepicker-inside-a-bootstrap-modal-wont-work-in-firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It look like a kind of z-index story but I'm not sure....*

One way is to insert the `datepicker` into the modal div, after it has been initialized:

**JSFiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/ye25dnub/1/

**JS** :

```
    $('#fecha_registro,#oi_ingreso_date,#oi_int_date,#fecha_nacimiento_add_pac,#r1_fecha_nacimiento_add_pac,#r2_fecha_nacimiento_add_pac').datepicker({
       dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
        prevText: 'Ant',
        nextText: 'Sig',
        currentText: 'Hoy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1900:2100'   
    });
$('#ui-datepicker-div').appendTo($('#modal_form_paciente'));
```

Comment: It´s incredible what can do i line of code, thanx you my friend ! its work perfectly cros browers even in movil.