# Use jQuery DatePicker in Bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to use **jQuery UI datepicker** in a modal. The real problem is that if I want to also show years and months, it shows me empty selects:

[image: Date picker months and years problem]

Using firebug, it seems that the option tags are under the modal.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <form id="add-form" action="#" method="post">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Add</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group">
      <label for="date">Date</label>
      <input type="text" id="date" name="date" class="form-control datepicker"/>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
 defaultDate: new Date(),
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true
});

$('.datepicker').css("z-index","0");
```

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21088713/1992780) but it doesn't work (I have the same problem of [giuseppe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059598/implementing-jquery-datepicker-in-bootstrap-modal/21088713#comment32692278_21088713)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21088713/1992780). The only option you needed is enforceFocus.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/93eTU/16/)**

**jQuery**

```
// Since confModal is essentially a nested modal it's enforceFocus method
// must be no-op'd or the following error results 
// "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
// But then when the nested modal is hidden we reset modal.enforceFocus
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
```

Comment: Did you try to insert the code above (not the one from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21088713/1992780)?

Comment: yes, and it didn't worked. I sorted out by changing the z-indexes of the modal to lower than that of datepicker. Thanks

Comment: Even enforceModalFocusFn is not required. Removing first line is also fine.

Answer (score 3):

Only had to add this style:

```
<style>
.ui-datepicker{
    z-index: 9999999 !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

i could not get `$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};` to work becuase the 'focusin.bs.modal' event was already attached to the modal.
this is the code i got to work; because the date picker is called after the modal opens. using the `beforeShow()` and `onClose` function i was able to turn the focus event off and on

```js
var datepicker_opts = {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    altFormat: "yymmdd",
    setDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: new Date()     
  };

BootboxContent = function(){    
var frm_str = '<form id="some-form">'
+'<div class="form-group">'
+ '<label for="date">Date</label>'    
+ '<input id="date" class="date span2 form-control input-sm" size="16" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" type="text">'
+ '</div>'
+ '</form>';

  var object = $('<div/>').html(frm_str).contents();

  object.find('.date').datepicker(
    $.extend({
      beforeShow: function(elem, inst) {
        $(document).off('focusin.bs.modal');
      },
      onClose: function(selectedDate, inst) {
        $modal = $(inst.input[0]).closest(".modal").data('bs.modal');
        $modal.enforceFocus(); 
      }
    }, datepicker_opts)
   );

   return object
  }
 $('.add_date_btn').on('click', function () {
       bootbox.dialog({
           message: BootboxContent,
           title: "View modal with date",
           buttons: {
               cancelar: {
                   label: "Cancel",
                   className: "btn-default"
               }
           }
       });
   }); //End click
```

```css
.hidden-form #add_class_form {
  display:none; 
}
.ui-datepicker{
 z-index: 9999999 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/releases/download/v4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>




<button class="add_date_btn btn btn-primary btn-sm">View modal with date</button>
```