# Prevent element inside modal from closing the modal with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a mess of js right now and there are too many things across a bunch of different files (inherited) and I'm having trouble with one last piece.

I have a modal containing a form and everything works fine except the selectboxes. Once the user clicks the select box it fires the close function. I've tried everything I can remember but I can't remember the proper terms for what I'm trying to do so I can't google it.

[Here's a quick fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dw3d5pgo/)

Code:

```
<div class="modal">
<select>
    <option>Select an option</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

And js:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    if(!$(event.target).is(".modal")){
        $(".modal").hide();
    };
});
```

This works normally for anything I put in there except selectboxes.

UPDATE: Ok so I was completely wrong with this question and made a few incorrect assumptions in my testing. This is not related to selectboxes but specifically to jQuery datepicker-ui selects. So this question is a duplicate of a few others on Stackoverflow and it can be closed as duplicate. One of the duplicate questions I found was: [Implementing jQuery DatePicker in Bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059598/implementing-jquery-datepicker-in-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing jQuery DatePicker in Bootstrap modal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059598/implementing-jquery-datepicker-in-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) refers to the element from where the event originated, so when you click on the `select` element `e.target` is the `select` element then the `$(event.target).is(".modal")` test will fail.

So the solution is to check whether the event's target is inside a `.modal` element for which you can use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) as below

```
$(document).click(function(){
    if(!$(event.target).closest(".modal").length){
        $(".modal").hide();
    };
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ep10aqzd/)

Comment: I have used this solution and it works in the simple demo, I think my problem on my actual document is that the selects are children of other children and so forth. I do not know how many levels there are but this solution only works if the selects are direct children of .modal.