# Datepicker won't open in a bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a simple modal in my view with a datepicker input field. I followed some instructions from answers in stack overflow, but what I have still doesn't work and I don't know why.

Here is the script part from my asp.net mvc view :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#mdl').on('click', function () {
       var parent = $(this).closest('.jumbotron');
       var name = parent.find('input[name="NAME_OF_MODEL"]').val();
       var id = parent.find('input[name="ID_OF_MODEL"]').val();
       console.log(id);
       //var titleLocation = $('#myModal').find('.modal-body'); modal - title
       var titleLocation = $('#myModal').find('.modal-title');
       titleLocation.text(name);

       // for each information you'll have to do like above...

       $('#myModal').modal('show');

     });
});

    $(function () {
        $('.date-picker').datepicker();
    })


</script>
```

And here is the modal  :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            <input class='date-picker' />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your modal exist when the page is first rendered, or is it being added dynamically (e.g. using ajax) in which case you would need to attach the plugin after it has been added

Comment: It is not added dynamically.

Comment: Your scripts are in the wrong order - `jquery` then `jquery-ui` :)

Comment: still won't work..

Comment: Try the answer from this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059598/implementing-jquery-datepicker-in-bootstrap-modal/21088713#21088713

Comment: Then what errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (DisplayListOfRolesUser:95)
    at j (jquery.min.js:1)
    at k (jquery.min.js:1)

Comment: Your datepicker (input) element should be present in the DOM when you initialize it with `$('.date-picker').datepicker();`

Comment: Check that you do not have additional copies of `jquery` in the view or layout (e.g. in bundles)

Comment: @StephenMuecke seem that i do have some in scripts

Comment: You need to make sure there are no duplicates, and the scripts are in the correct order (the message suggests you might have another copy of `jquery` loaded after `jquery-ui` (which wipes out `jquery-ui`)

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is related to the order of the libraries:

change the order from:

- jquery-ui.css
- jquery-ui.min.js
- jquery.min.js

to:

- jquery.min.js
- jquery-ui.css
- jquery-ui.min.js

So the result is:

```js
$(function () {

  $('#mdl').on('click', function () {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.jumbotron');
    var name = parent.find('input[name="NAME_OF_MODEL"]').val();
    var id = parent.find('input[name="ID_OF_MODEL"]').val();
    console.log(id);
    //var titleLocation = $('#myModal').find('.modal-body'); modal - title
    var titleLocation = $('#myModal').find('.modal-title');
    titleLocation.text(name);

    // for each information you'll have to do like above...

    $('#myModal').modal('show');

  });
  $('.date-picker').datepicker();

});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn" id="mdl">Click Me</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                <input class='date-picker'/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i did as you suggested, but it still doesn't work. I see that your snippet works, so any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: @RobertRoss Insert the js code in the dom ready. Snippet updated. Let me know if you continue to get errors

Comment: @getanoM , i am still getting Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (DisplayListOfRolesUser:96)
    at fire (jquery-1.10.2.js:3062)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery-1.10.2.js:3108)
    at init.ready (jquery-1.10.2.js:285)
    at init (jquery-1.10.2.js:228)
    at jQuery (jquery-1.10.2.js:77)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (DisplayListOfRolesUser:95)
    at j (jquery.min.js:1)
    at k (jquery.min.js:1)

Comment: From your error message and your html fragment i see you have included two different version of jQuery libraries. Take a deep look inside your code and use only one jQuery library and after that include a compatible jQuery ui library.  I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

to things must to be done:

1. Add this to your css:

```
.datepicker-panel {
   z-index: 9999 !important; /* has to be larger than 1050 */
}
.datepicker-container {
   z-index: 9999 !important; /* has to be larger than 1050 */
}
```

2. Add this to your js

```
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    container: '#my-modal',
  });
```