# Jquery Colorbox Freezes IE when contained in a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, colorbox

On IE, I had a Colorbox popup contained in a Bootstrap modal. Whenever I open the popup, it opens, but then IE freezes and I have to stop the process to get it to close. It just sits entirely dead.

I'm not really sure why it does this, as the examples work fine on IE, it's only mine that breaks.

Here's the containing div with my colorbox. It's contained within a bootstrap modal.

```
<div class='thumbnails-controls'>
 <a colorbox ng-href='{{baseAssetUrl+userID}}/{{asset.asset_uuid}}' class="preview search-thumbnail" title="{{asset.asset_name}}"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
 <a ng-click="deleteAsset(asset.asset_id)" href="#" title="delete" class="delete-thumbnail"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
</div>
```

I'm also using AngularJS, I don't think that would cause issues, would it? I thought maybe it was the CSS, so I commented it out, but it still froze IE. As did hard coding an image URL, that still froze. I also tried loading the image in an iFrame, it still froze. I also, just to try stuff, changed ng-href to just href, and it still froze.

It only does this in IE. Every other browser works fine. I'm at a loss on why this is not working.

Comment: I just commented out Bootstrap's import and it no longer freezes. However, Bootstrap is required for this project, so is there a reason they'd conflict?

Comment: The colorbox and bootstrap javascript may be interfering with each other in some way, or may be triggering something unexpected in Angular. I would try commenting out any listeners or callbacks attached to colorbox or bootstrap events. Also, is the modal within a modal required by the project, or could they be separate?  Further help would require looking at the javascript in a jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: Basically, the client clicks a button and opens a gallery of their assets. Every asset thumbnail has a preview button, clicking it opens up the colorbox modal to show the full sized preview. 

This functionality is already complete, this is just a maintenance task, so I don't really want to redo the preview system to use another library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was a conflict of focus between the Bootstrap modal and Colorbox modal. For whatever reason IE was being picky about it, other browsers got over the conflict more smoothly.

Through Google and several hours of about a billion different search word combinations, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649459/twitter-bootstrap-multiple-modal-error), which was about 2 bootstrap modals, but it worked to fix my issue.

The answer for me that worked from that question was adding

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {};
```

After all my Javascript imports loaded. Tested across Chrome, Firefox and IE, it appears to be working just fine.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19190216/3022659), seems like a better fix, however, I couldn't get it to work properly for me, and just overriding the default behavior worked for me.