# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have been  confusing for a week for this eror in my javascript. i have table with one column as anchor for selection code. if this view display on screen is not problem, java script is doing normal. But if this view display on jquery dialog with ajax, when i click anchor class "pilih" get error:
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

i am sorry i can't explain very well, because my code mixed PHP and java script.

anyone can access my web and page problem in this link

http://femiola.com/public/cbarang/#

there is PLUS BUTTON > CLICK IT, appear bootstrap modal,
than BLUE BUTTON > CLICK IT, appear jquery dialog,
when i choosed one anchor in jquery dialog have error Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

my code is here

```
VBARANG.PHP (screen page with PLUS BUTTON)
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
           $(".plihkel").on('click', function(e){

                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    var ygdipilih = $(this).attr("id");
                    alert(ygdipilih)



               });        

});

</script>

VBANTUANKEL.PHP - JQuery Dialog


   <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" width="40%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Kode</th>
            <th>Kelompok</th>
            <th>Pilih</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($daftarkelbarang as $row): ?>
        <tr>
           <td><a href="#" class="plihkel" id="<?php echo $row['kdkel'];?>"><?php echo $row['kdkel'];?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['nmkel'];?></td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
     <?php endforeach ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

why this on click eror if display on jquery dialog, but not eror when display on screen?

Comment: Need more details. For me [this](http://jsfiddle.net/53Lyhe1v/) works fine except I added `e.preventDefault()` to the handler, so it don't try to load another page.

Comment: sorry too long response...thanks for comment @panfil i give example page problem at link above, could you help me? thanks...

Comment: Using two frameworks with pretty intersecting functionality is not a good idea. There will be conflicts such as this, when two modal dialog widgets conflics. I recommend you to use bootstrap modal for both dialogs. But If you need just fix an issue you can put `$(".plihkel").on('focus', false);` somewhere in `ready` callback.

Comment: thanks @panfil for your answer, i have done what were you suggest..but it get error too..

Comment: My bad. Anyway [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649459/twitter-bootstrap-multiple-modal-error) the solution: just add `$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};` somwere in `ready`.

Comment: i accept your suggestion i used bootstrap modal too.. not combine with jquery dialog and it's done well... thank you panfil...