# Bootstrap modal called from jQuery UI Dialog: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I've a bit of a strange problem. I'm calling a Bootstrap Modal whilst there's a jQuery UI Dialog open and am getting `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.` in the console

Strangely this only happens when I call the Modal when there's a Dialog open.
It doesn't appear to have any noticeable side effects, although I'd rather the error not be there.

I also get the same error when I click either button within the Bootstrap Modal.

I'm using Bootstrap version 4.1.0, jQuery version 3.3.1 and jQuery UI version 1.12.1

Due to the way the application's built, I need the Dialog to be modal but then have the Bootstrap Modal to popup over the top of it when a specific action is taken in said dialog.
Changing the modal status of the Dialog before showing the Bootstrap Modal doesn't seem to solve the issue either.

Although I have a feeling it could be related to having both set as modal, is there something obvious I've missed here?

The entire project is a complex and massive, so I've put a couple of snippets below:

```js
//jQuery UI Dialog definition:

Dialog = $("#dialogContainer").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 400,
  width: "80%",
  modal: true,
  show: {
    effect: "fade",
    duration: 250
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "fade",
    duration: 250
  },
  buttons: {
    "Save Sale": {
      text: "Save",
      id: "Module_Dialog_Save",
      click: function() {
        //Handler code
      }
    },
    Cancel: {
      text: "Cancel",
      id: "Module_Dialog_Cancel",
      click: function() {
        //Handler code
      }
    }
  },
  close: function() {
    //Handler code
  }
});
//Show dialog
$( "#dialogContainer" ).dialog( "open" );
function Delete(){
$('#bootStrapModal').modal("hide");
}
function Cancel(){
$('#bootStrapModal').modal("hide");
}
function buttonClick(){
$('#bootStrapModal').modal();
}
//Bootstrap modal call - error happens when this is called
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialogContainer"><button onClick="buttonClick()">This Errors</button></div>
<div class="modal fade" id="bootStrapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
 <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
  <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalCenterTitle">Delete?</h5>
  <button id="CloseButton" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    Are you sure you want to delete?<br>
    Changes won't be saved until you click Save
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
  <button id="CancelButton" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="Cancel()">Close</button>
  <button id="DeleteButton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="Delete()">Delete</button>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for you but it didn't work. So please add more code. –

Comment: Duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649459/twitter-bootstrap-multiple-modal-error

Comment: @RecepKaradas unfortunately not, that doesn't solve the issue. That's also for bootstrap 2, not 4. That also deals with multiple Bootstrap modals, not a Bootstrap modal over a jQuery UI Dialog

Comment: Ok sorry, if you tried that and that didn't fix your problem. The error message is the same, so it could be related.

Comment: It's cool, I have tried a couple of permutations of solutions proposed in that article as I found it earlier. No dice unfortunately. If this has been answered on SO before though, I haven't found it thus far.

Comment: What about $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function () {}; mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48280549/1390791

Comment: @Recep Karadas That appears to have fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Great and no problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Recep Karadas, this post has the answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48280549/1390791

In Bootstrap 4, enforceFocus has been renamed to _enforceFocus.

Answer (score 15):

Removing `tabindex="-1"` from modal works for me:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="bootStrapModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call another dialog inside the open one. HTML will look like this:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="dialogContainer">
    <button onClick="buttonClick()">This Errors</button>
</div>

<div id="another-dialogContainer" title="second Container">
    Second Modal here
</div>
```

then on your javascript you just call the second dialog when button is cliked

```
Dialog = $("#dialogContainer").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 200,
    width: "50%",
    modal: true,
    show: {
           effect: "fade",
           duration: 250
          },
    hide: {
           effect: "fade",
           duration: 250
          },
    buttons: {
            "Save Sale": {
                        text: "Save",
                        id: "Module_Dialog_Save",
                        click: function() {
                              //Handler code
                         }
                       },
             Cancel: {
                       text: "Cancel",
                       id: "Module_Dialog_Cancel",
                       click: function() {
                        //Handler code
                          }
                        }
                      },
        close: function() {
           //Handler code
            }
         });
     //Show dialog
     $( "#dialogContainer" ).dialog( "open" );

function buttonClick(){
     $( "#another-dialogContainer" ).dialog('open');
  }

  //second dialog Container

$( "#another-dialogContainer" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
     }
 });
```

then you can put some style

```
.ui-dialog {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: .2em;
    border:1px;

}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    border:1px;
    display: none;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
    border: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#CAAD75;
    background-color: #FDF8E4;
    overflow: auto;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
    text-align: left;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    background-image: none;
    margin-top: .5em;
    padding: .3em 1em .5em .4em;
    background-color: #846733;
 }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
    float: right;

}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button {
    margin: .5em .4em .5em 0;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.ui-dialog .ui-resizable-se {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
    background-position: 16px 16px;

}
.ui-draggable-handle {
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none;
}
```

[snippet here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BEMoey)

Comment: That's not quite what I'm trying to do. That's opening two jQuery UI dialogs, whereas I'm trying to open a Bootstrap Modal over the top of a jQuery UI dialog. My code appears to work, I'm just trying to remove the error.