# How can I restore an overwritten native function

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

Just a though experiment, say I decided to prevent `eval()` from being run in my node application, and I ran added something like:

```
global['eval'] = function(args){ this.console.log(`eval attempted: ${args}`); }
```

Is there any way to restore eval without restarting the application?

Comment: Notice, that [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) behaves differently when it is aliased.

Answer (score 4):

If you save a reference to the function, yes.

```
const originalEval = global.eval;
global.eval = function(args){ this.console.log(`eval attempted: ${args}`);}

function restore() {
  global.eval = originalEval;
}
```

Comment: Here too is the same concept from one of my own very well received answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19190216/34806

Comment: How about if this wasn't an option? :P